# NodeJS deployment fails with Error: Failed to get status of deployment. using Visual Code

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-code

I followed [this](https://medium.com/@mario_shenal/deploying-node-js-application-on-azure-app-service-using-bicep-files-468ec1e80fa8) tutorial to set up a node application and deploy to my azure account.

In VS code, when I try to deploy the app, it packages to 13.2 kb and then it just says "Error: Failed to get status of deployment." There are no logs on the deployment page of the App Service and no indication that the deployment happens.

Is there anywhere I should be looking for logs to figure out why it appears to timeout or a manual way to run the deployment that the App Service Extension is doing under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you encounter deployment issues with Azure App Service from Visual Studio Code, it can be challenging to diagnose the problem without specific error messages. However, there are several steps you can take to troubleshoot the issue:

1. **Check Visual Studio Code Output:**
   Look for any error messages or additional information in the "Output" pane of Visual Studio Code. Switch to the "Azure" tab and explore the output related to the deployment process.
2. **Azure Portal Logs:**
   Go to the Azure Portal and navigate to your App Service. In the left-hand menu, under the "Monitoring" section, select "App Service logs." Enable Application Logging (Filesystem) and detailed error messages. After making these changes, try deploying again and check the logs for any specific error messages.
3. **Azure CLI Deployment:**
   You can try deploying your Node.js application using the Azure CLI manually. Open a terminal and use the following commands:

   ```
   az login  # Log in to your Azure account
   az webapp up -n <your-app-name> -g <your-resource-group> --sku B1
   ```

   Replace `<your-app-name>` with your App Service name and `<your-resource-group>` with your Azure resource group. This can provide more detailed error messages in the terminal.
4. **Azure App Service Extension Logs:**
   The Azure App Service extension for Visual Studio Code typically uses the Azure CLI under the hood. You might find more information in the Azure CLI logs. Open a terminal in VS Code and run:

   ```
   az --debug webapp deployment show -n <your-app-name> -g <your-resource-group>
   ```

   This command will show detailed debug information about the deployment process.
5. **Check Node.js Version:**
   Ensure that the version of Node.js specified in your `package.json` file is compatible with the version supported by Azure App Service. You can check the supported Node.js versions for Azure App Service [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-configure-nodejs#specify-version).
6. **Review Deployment Script:**
   If you have a deployment script (commonly in the `.deployment` and `.deployment/config` files), ensure that it is correctly configured.
7. **Network Issues:**
   Ensure there are no network-related issues. Sometimes, network problems can lead to timeouts during deployment.
8. **Update Azure CLI and Extensions:**
   Make sure you have the latest version of the Azure CLI and the Azure App Service extension installed in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: The specific thing that solved my issue was to go to the extensions page and click reload until everything was updated. Then the deployments just worked. Seems like it must have been some transient error that resulted from an update on one of the extensions.